# SFTP partial authentication using publickey,password preferred authentication methods

Tags: sftp, public-key

I'm encountering an issue when attempting to connect to an SFTP server that requires both public key *and* password authentication.

The source server is a fully up-to-date CentOS 7 server (SFTP debug shows `OpenSSH_7.4p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`). The intention is a simple bash script to grab a load of files.

When connecting without specifying the preferred authentications order (i.e. when using the default `publickey,password`) it gets stuck in a loop of providing the key and never requesting the password:

```
sftp -v -i uat.key -oBatchMode=no <username>@<host>
...
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: uat.key
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: uat.key
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Trying private key: uat.key
Authenticated with partial success.
...loops forever
```

When reversing the auth methods it then requests the password 3 times before proceeding (successfully!), which obviously causes issues with automation:

```
sftp -v -i uat.key -oPreferredAuthentications=password,publickey -oBatchMode=no <username>@<host>
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: password
<username>@<host>'s password:
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
Permission denied, please try again.
<username>@<host>'s password:
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
Permission denied, please try again.
<username>@<host>'s password:
Authenticated with partial success.
debug1: Authentications that can continue: password,publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: uat.key
debug1: Authentication succeeded (publickey).
Authenticated to <username>@<host> ([<ip>]:22).
debug1: channel 0: new [client-session]
debug1: Entering interactive session.
debug1: pledge: network
debug1: Sending environment.
debug1: Sending env LANG = en_GB.UTF-8
debug1: Sending subsystem: sftp
Connected to <username>@<host>.
sftp> exit
```

My digging has led me to this [IBM article](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1IC87654) from 2012 which covers the second issue, however I have not been able to find a workaround for my partial auth loop in the first command.

Can anyone more savvy with OpenSSH shed some light on this issue?